# SugarCRM: Month and Year selector is not working in datepicker

Tags: sugarcrm

I have a situation like when status changes, the dialog window will open. In that dialog window I have 3 date fields. I used SugarCRM's default date picker. But when I want to change the year and month, the selector/input is not working. In fact on clicking these, the mouse pointer focuses in the first input field.

My code is below:

```
$.each(calenderSets, function(index, value){
        Calendar.setup ({
            inputField : index,//input field Id
            ifFormat : cal_date_format,
            daFormat : cal_date_format,
            button : value,//calender icon ID
            singleClick : true,
            dateStr : "",
            step : 1,
            weekNumbers:false
        });
    });
```

And Dialog window:

```
dialog = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog('dialog1', {
        width: winWidth,
        fixedcenter : "contained",
        visible : false,
        draggable: true,
        position: 'absolute',
        close:true,
        centered: true,
        /*effect:[{effect:YAHOO.widget.ContainerEffect.SLIDE, duration:0.2},
                {effect:YAHOO.widget.ContainerEffect.FADE,duration:0.2}],*/
        modal:true
    });
    dialog.setHeader("All * marked fields are required");
    dialog.setBody(Body here);
    dialog.setFooter('<button title="save" type="button" class="report-scheduler-btn" name="save" onClick="saveInvoiceDetails()">Save</button>');
    dialog.render(document.body);
    dialog.show();
    setCalenderToDateFields();
```

[image]

Comment: Check on console the error message and update the actual error message.

Comment: There is no error in the console. You can see the screenshot. On clicking the month dropdown or Year input, the cursor goes to first input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found and fixed this issue by adding the following to custom/themes/default/css/style.css:

```
.yui-calcontainer .yui-cal-nav {
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Because my date picker (as is yours) is within a UI dialog container, the default z-index of 3 in the .yui-cal-nav class isn't high enough to interact with the form fields in the date nav section (despite being able to see them). The overlay for my UI dialog has a z-index of 1000, so setting the z-index of .yui-cal-nav to 1001 put it high enough that I could interact with the form fields.